# Mirror Relational Databases to RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb, symmetricds, database-mirroring

I found this article [Sync Relational Databases to NoSQL like MongoDB](https://www.jumpmind.com/blog/mongodb-synchronization) and was sad to see only MongoDB on the dropdown list: [image]

Is it possible to sync a relational database to RethinkDB with SymmetricDS or any other similar tool?

Answer (score 1):

It should be, but you’d need to add yourself support for it. The process is quite straightforward once you understood how it works for other database managers (mostly copy/paste with some modifications and lots of tryouts)

Comment: You could also enter an issue at https://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view_all_bug_page.php requesting the feature.  No guarantees that it will be implemented, but it would have a shot at making the next feature release.